# What app did Dell pre-install to indicate capslock, numlock, etc?

Tags: windows, keyboard, software-rec

I just bought a new Dell Studio 1747, unfortunately it does not have any indicator lights for Caps lock, Num lock, etc. It seems Dell provided a software solution to the problem, as when I first played with the system a notification would popup. However, Dell also installed a bunch of software I did not want, so I formatted. Now I can't seem to find and reinstall the software solution...

What app did Dell pre-install to indicate capslock, numlock?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently the application is called: [Dell QuickSet](http://support.us.dell.com/support/downloads/download.aspx?c=us&l=en&s=gen&releaseid=R204480&formatcnt=1&libid=0&typeid=-1&dateid=-1&formatid=-1&fileid=285125)

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to rely on a third-party program, however. You can use the accessibility features of Windows to audibly/visual notify you when you've pressed the Caps Lock key. Follow these steps:

1. Display the Control Panel.
2. Double-click the Accessibility Options applet. The Accessibility Options dialog box opens.
3. Make sure the Keyboard tab is displayed. (Click here to see a related figure.)
4. Choose the Use ToggleKeys check box.
5. Display the General tab. (Click here to see a related figure.)
6. Make sure the Turn Off Accessibility Features After Idle check box is not selected.
7. Click OK.
8. Close the Control Panel.

The ToggleKeys feature, when turned on, will beep whenever the Caps Lock, Num Lock, or Scroll Lock keys are pressed and its shows a small window for that.

[Source](http://word.tips.net/Pages/T000336_Notification_when_Caps_Lock_is_Active.html)

Comment: Thanks! I tried using toggle keys, but I usually have my sound turned off; I would really like a visual solution.

Answer (score 0):

Our Dell Studio 1737 has lights under the respective keys.  I'm glad it's not just a software solution for us.